# img.height problem (returning 0 everytime)

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="img-section">
    </div>
</body>
```

and javascript

```
const init = function () {
    var pic = document.createElement("img");
    pic.src = "soflogo.png";
    var src = document.getElementsByClassName("img-section")[0];
    src.appendChild(pic);
    let image = document.querySelector("img");
    image.addEventListener("load", function() {
        height = pic.height;
        console.log(height);//this usually returns right value
    })
    console.log(pic.height);//this always returns 0
    console.log(height);//this returns error (not defined for sure)
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

I need to work with height of image. In the javascript code, I want to add the image on the page and then I want to do something with the img.height. I tried to use the load event, which works usually good (every 10th refresh console.log(height); returns strange values, like 0 or absolutely nothing). So I need to fix that console.log(pic.height); always returns 0 (right below the load event).
Thank you
(sorry for my bad english)

EDIT: Thank you for your answers. But there comes another problem. The code above is just an example of my project. The main task is to put images into three div tags. I hoped, that the height issue fix will repair it, but it didn't. So, this is my main project:

```
const init = function () {

    let allGalleryData = [{
        galleryName: "Terénní seminář 2015",
        galleryThumbnailUrl: "gallery/Fotoseminar2015/",
        galleryFullSizeUrl: "gallery/Fotoseminar2015/big",
        galleryImages: [
            { url: '01.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.5, people: 91 },
            { url: '02.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.9, people: 42 },
            { url: '03.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 5, people: 19 },
            { url: '04.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.6, people: 31 },
            { url: '05.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.2, people: 20 },
            { url: '06.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.1, people: 43 },
            { url: '07.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.2, people: 21 },
            { url: '08.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.1, people: 82 },
            { url: '09.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.7, people: 18 },
            { url: '10.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.1, people: 58 },
            { url: '11.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.8, people: 98 },
            { url: '12.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.8, people: 25 },
            { url: '13.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.5, people: 41 },
            { url: '14.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.4, people: 33 },
            { url: '15.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.1, people: 28 },
            { url: '16.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.1, people: 53 },
            { url: '17.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.7, people: 24 },
            { url: '18.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.1, people: 72 },
            { url: '19.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.5, people: 96 },
            { url: '20.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.4, people: 3 },
            { url: '21.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.6, people: 32 },
            { url: '22.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.1, people: 45 },
            { url: '23.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.2, people: 23 },
            { url: '24.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.8, people: 19 },
            { url: '25.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 3.8, people: 13 },
            { url: '26.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 4.7, people: 71 },
            { url: '27.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 2.3, people: 96 },
            { url: '28.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.5, people: 84 },
            { url: '29.jpg', title: 'something', stars: 1.3, people: 13 }
        ]
    },
    {
        galleryName: "Skotsko 2014",
        galleryThumbnailUrlS: "gallery/Skotsko/",
        galleryFullSizeUrl: "gallery/Skotsko/big",
        galleryImagesNameUrl: [
            { url: 'Sk2014_01.JPG', title: 'Kanál v Amsterodamu', stars: 1.1, people: 24 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_02.JPG', title: 'Amsterodam (pobřeží)', stars: 3.4, people: 36 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_03.JPG', title: 'Trajekt do UK', stars: 1.3, people: 16 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_04.JPG', title: 'Pobřeží Skotska', stars: 3, people: 35 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_05.JPG', title: 'Urquhart Castle', stars: 2.3, people: 38 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_06.JPG', title: 'Břeh jezera', stars: 2.4, people: 50 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_07.JPG', title: 'Eilean Donan Castle', stars: 3.1, people: 31 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_08.JPG', title: 'Skotský skot', stars: 3.1, people: 40 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_09.JPG', title: 'The Old Man of Storr, Skye', stars: 2.9, people: 68 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_10.JPG', title: 'The Old Man of Storr, Skye', stars: 5, people: 71 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_11.JPG', title: 'Culloden', stars: 3.6, people: 45 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_12.JPG', title: 'Cawdor Castle', stars: 3.7, people: 31 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_13.JPG', title: 'Cairn Gorm', stars: 4.8, people: 77 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_14.JPG', title: 'Cairngorms National Park', stars: 4.8, people: 64 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_15.JPG', title: 'Tower Bridge', stars: 2.9, people: 61 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_16.JPG', title: 'Butler\'s Wharf', stars: 3.7, people: 78 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_17.JPG', title: 'London Eye', stars: 1.4, people: 85 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_18.JPG', title: 'Covent garden market - London', stars: 1.4, people: 76 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_19.JPG', title: 'Buckinghamský palác', stars: 2.4, people: 24 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_20.JPG', title: 'Big Ben London', stars: 4.2, people: 91 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_21.JPG', title: 'Big Ben London', stars: 3.5, people: 39 },
            { url: 'Sk2014_22.JPG', title: 'Big Ben London', stars: 3.7, people: 83 }
        ]
    }
    ]
    let column1Lenth = 0;
    let column2Lenth = 0;
    let column3Lenth = 0;
    let height;
    let source;
    let path;
    let image;
    for (const i of allGalleryData) {
        let seminar = i.galleryThumbnailUrl;
        let skotsko = i.galleryThumbnailUrlS;
        if (i.galleryImages) {
            for (const img of i.galleryImages) {
                path = seminar + img.url;
                let pic = document.createElement("img");
                pic.src = path;
                image = document.querySelector("img");
                image.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    height = pic.height;
                    if ((column1Lenth <= column2Lenth) && (column1Lenth <= column3Lenth)) {
                        column1Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column1")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if (((column2Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column2Lenth <= column3Lenth))) {
                        column2Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column2")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if ((column3Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column3Lenth < column2Lenth)) {
                        column3Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column3")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            for (const img of i.galleryImagesNameUrl) {
                path = skotsko + img.url;
                let pic = document.createElement("img");
                pic.src = path;
                image = document.querySelector("img");
                image.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    height = pic.height;
                    if ((column1Lenth <= column2Lenth) && (column1Lenth <= column3Lenth)) {
                        column1Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column1")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if (((column2Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column2Lenth <= column3Lenth))) {
                        column2Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column2")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                    else if ((column3Lenth < column1Lenth) && (column3Lenth < column2Lenth)) {
                        column3Lenth += height;
                        source = document.getElementsByClassName("column3")[0];
                        source.appendChild(pic);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

And still, if I refresh the site, there's a big chance, that the height is still 0. Even if I use the load event. Actually, I was referring to this problem in the javascript code below (`//this USSUALLY returns right value`). So does anyone have any idea, how to fix this? (I am very new at javascript, like three months, so I don't understand to the promise and async)

Comment: Don't read the value before the image really is loaded.

Comment: Well just after manipulating the dom it doesn't change the state right away, so you will still get the empty image element thus height remains 0, only after the first reload the you get the proper dom and thus you get the height inside the function.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the follow up question as a separate question; we try to keep questions here focused on one topic at a time to make it more likely to be relevant for future searchers.

Comment: OK, I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onload is called after the height is printed before the image is actually loaded hence the reason for zero height.

Comment: Thanks! But how to fix it?

Comment: why do you need to print outside or use value outside. Just use the event listner for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change your `init` to `async` and create a function which essentialy return a promise once the load event has finished and `await` for that promise to finish like:

```js
const loadPromise = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
  img.src = url;
})
const init = async function () {
    var pic = document.createElement("img");
    pic.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
    var src = document.getElementsByClassName("img-section")[0];
    src.appendChild(pic);
    const img = await loadPromise(pic.src);
    //height = pic.height;
    console.log(img.height);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

```html
<div class="img-section"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous patterns are something you need to get used to throughout any JavaScript. Waiting for an image to load is just one example of something asynchronously occurring. Almost every time you have this pattern:

```
doSomethingAsync(..., function() {
  // Thing A
});
// Thing B
```

...Thing B will come before Thing A. The function in `doSomethingAsync` is called a callback, and it's not called until the async thing happened.

You can't work around asynchronicity in JavaScript. To get a Thing B to happen after Thing A, either place Thing B inside the same callback:

```
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
  height = pic.height;
  // Do something with height
});
```

...or wrap the async thing in a Promise which will let you sequence things in a way that maybe feels more natural or intuitive, plus will let you decrease the levels of nesting in the code.

```
function waitForEvent(obj, eventName) {
  return new Promise(resolve => obj.addEventListener(eventName, resolve));
}

async function getImageHeight(image) {
  await waitForEvent(image, 'load');
  return image.height;
}

// Chaining style
getImageHeight(pic)
  .then(height => {
    // Do something with height
    return nextAsyncThing();
  })
  .then(dataFromOtherAsyncThing => {
    // ...
  });
```

...or better yet, use an async function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const pic = document.createElement("img");
  pic.src = "soflogo.png";
  document.getElementsByClassName("img-section")[0].appendChild(pic);

  const height = await getImageHeight(pic)
  console.log(height);  // Should have the height
});
```